# How to implement class operators without creating new objects?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, c++17

Minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class myint{
public:
    int x;
    myint(int x) { this->x = x;}
    ~myint() {cout << "DEL" << endl; }
    myint operator += (int const &y) { this->x += y; return y;}
};


int main() {

    myint i = myint(2);
    i += 3;

}
```

I'm confused why the object i is destructed twice. How do I avoid this? I will have large objects and will want to optimize the code. I do not want new objects creating when using basic operators.

Comment: `myint& operator += (int const &y) { this->x += y; return *this;}` read about operators overload. `operator+=` updates the object. So it should return its modified version. Then you can write things like: `(i += 3) += 5;`

Comment: Read about operator overloading good practices. The general form for this one could be something like : `myint &operator += (int const &y) { this->x += y; return *this;}`

Comment: Related: [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Comment: Thanks! I'm coming from Python, so there are a lot of details for me to catch on.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you returning `y`? You should return `*this`. Also make the return type `myint&`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class myint {
public:
    int x;
    myint(int x) { this->x = x; }
    ~myint() { cout << "DEL" << endl; }
    myint& operator += (int const &y) { this->x += y; return *this; }
};


int main() {

    myint i = myint(2);
    i += 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example when you `return y;` compiler will make implicit conversion and create `myint` by itself. Take a look [Explicit keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/a/121163/7476661).

So, because of that 2 objects are created insead of one. First object in your main function and second temporary object in your `operator +=`. When we have two objects we have two descructor calls when `main` function finishes.

**Solution**

Use reference and explicit keyword for safety:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class myint {
public:
    int x;
    explicit myint(int x) { this->x = x;}
    ~myint() {cout << "DEL " <<endl; }
    myint& operator += (int const &y) { this->x += y; return *this;}
};

int main() {
    myint i = myint(2);
    i += 3;
}
```